# Automatic Paypal conversion for buyers

Tags: paypal, type-conversion

I have seen on ebay that some sellers have auto conversion for buyers
Seller accept payments only in USD, so if I have GBP and Im buyer I will need to convert my gbp to usd to pay for seller. 
How and where I can make this option available for me? help  please